# Spring data 1.6.0 GA cannot find entity manager factory bean by custom id

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have found the strange behavior of Spring data 1.6.0 (downgraded version 1.5.2 does not have this problem). It seems that this version strictly demands the id of entity manager factory bean to be "entityManagerFactory". If not, this error appears when running TestNG test:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with  name 'jpaMapppingContext': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#36b87404' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#36b87404': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined

My configuration is:

```
<!-- ************************************************************** -->
<!-- Database configuration                                     -->
<!-- ************************************************************** -->    

  <!-- Entity manager factory bean -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryCustomId"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="test-system" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array>
                <value>${pds.db.scan.model}</value>
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${jdbc.showsql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${jdb.formatsql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${jdbc.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

  <!-- C3P0 connection pool -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <!-- Connection properties -->
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <!-- Pool properties -->
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${pool.minsize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${pool.maxsize}" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${pool.initialPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="${pool.maxstatements}" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${pool.acquireincrement}" />
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="${jdbc.check}" />
        <property name="numHelperThreads" value="${pool.threads}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- JPA transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryCustomId" />
    </bean>

  <!-- Activate Spring Data JPA repository support -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="pds.archiva.db.repository" />
</code>
```

Is it a bug in Spring Data JPA or am I doing something wrong ? Tested on windows java 64bit 7u55 with following versions:

```
spring.framework.version = 4.0.5.RELEASE
spring.security.version = 3.2.4.RELEASE
spring.data-jpa.version = 1.6.0.RELEASE
```

As I have written, the same test works with only changing spring.data-jpa.version = 1.5.2.RELEASE ... or change id of bean to  "entityManagerFactory" instead of "entityManagerFactoryCustomId".

Comment: you have not defined an bean with id `entityManagerFactory`

Comment: set the entity manager explicitly then (see `entity-manager-factory-ref`element in `<jpa:repositories/>`. Looks like [the documentation might be outdated](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll Thanks, I missed to add entity-manager-factory-ref when editing and upgrade to new version ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just added @StéphaneNicoll answer:
set the entity manager explicitly then (see entity-manager-factory-refelement in jpa:repositories . Looks like the documentation might be outdated.